# Loader.element in google Chrome as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I load a file :

```
var aLoader:Loader = new Loader();
aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedEvent);
aLoader.load(new URLRequest(url_photo), new LoaderContext(true));

function onLoadedEvent(event:Event):void{
    var li:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
    var loader:Loader = li.loader;
    log(loader.content.width.toString());
}
```

On safari or firefox i have no problem to access at the content. But in Chrome it doesn't work and i found no error code.
Only Chrome seems to work with the crossdomain.xml. Is it a lose of the loaderContext ?

The log (which works) :

```
function log(msg:String, caller:Object = null):void{
    var str:String = "";
    if(caller){
        str = getQualifiedClassName(caller);
        str += ":: ";
    }
    str += msg;
    trace(str);
    if(ExternalInterface.available){
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", str);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: it seems to be a Pepper Flash bug..

Comment: aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedEvent); should be always placed prior to loading.

Comment: It's not in the same order in my code, sorry it's a copy/paste mistake.

But I used this type of solution :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735975/loader-complete-event-does-not-work-with-browser-as3